# Bluetooth Connecting two devices

Tags: audio, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I am trying to set up bluetooth so that I can play music from both my phone and my computer in alternation (ie, if I want to go in the other room on a call where the phone stops playing, i can switch over to my computer without disconnecting and reconnecting).

The first step in this is to connect two devices simultaneously, are there any packages which exist for this on raspberry pi and if not does anyone know how I would go about editing blueman or bluez or pulse audio to start this??

Thanks!

Matt

Comment: First of all, which raspberry do you have?

Comment: Well, you already named the packages you need. Can you explain where you are stuck?

Comment: Thank you guys! I have a sero and a 3, each running on raspbian stretch 9.1

Comment: I have actually gotten two devices connected I'll update below

Answer (score 0):

This isnt the whole path to the final product i discussed above, but for the meat of the question - How to connect two devices at once - all you need to do is change your rasp to a master device. Masters can connect to multiple slaves in the same piconet

the linux command for this is

```
hciconfig hci0 lm master,accept
```

make sure the 0 is correct it could actually be any number

Comment: I wonder why that is not the default …

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.